Is there a way to measure (bad) karma?
I'm new to this site, and if this question is silly or offensive, just tell me and I will delete it.
I have known some people in my life with bad luck dripping from their fingers, nearly everything they did went wrong and messed up, sometimes in a nearly unbelievable way.
Most of them were of average intelligence or above.
Is there a way to measure (bad) karma?

'measure' - no. Scriptures can act as to a guide as to what actions/thoughts can lead to good or bad karma, but how karma is 'measured' is not. And how the karma is being meted out by the Lord may be other than what you perceive.

@SwamiVishwananda I wasn't hoping for a cheep gadget that tells me my karma was "3.14159" or something. Maybe exact "measure" is too much to hope for.
